# Looping Through EXCEL VBA Dictionary

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I have a VBA Dictionary with the following data:

```
ID       NAME       POSITION 
5008004  John Doe   00120096
5008002  John Doe2  00117886
5010010  John Doe3  00117886
```

I have an Excel documented with the following cells:

```
POSITION    SUPERVISOR_NAME
00117886    John Doe
00117886    John Doe2
00117886    John Doe3
```

Current Excel VBA code loops through the dictionary in the following fashion:

```
If SUPERVISOR_NAME <> "" Then
    For Each myKey In superDictionary.Keys
            If superDictionary(myKey) = SUPERVISOR_NAME Then
                SUPERVISOR_NAME = myKey
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
End If
```

Resulting in replacing the JOHN DOE names with their associated IDs no matter what.

**Question:** How do I go about replacing the JOHN DOE names with their associated IDs BUT only when the POSITION and SUPERVISOR_NAME from EXCEL matches the Dictionary or ELSE submit nothing.

Comment: It's unclear to me how you are loading the dictionary. Is the key the ID and the item the Name? Wouldn't it make more sense to reverse that and use the [Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251562.aspx) method?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem like you are properly utilizing one of the most powerful features of a [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) object; that being its fast retrieval capabilities. You essentially want to perform a lookup with two-column criteria so use the two columns as your [key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ex01tte.aspx) and the ID as the [Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84k9x471.aspx).

[image: dictionary_lookup]

```
Option Explicit

Sub supervisorIDs()
    Dim d As Variant, dict As Object
    Dim v As Long, vVALs As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare  'default is vbbinarycompare

    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        'get values from worksheet
        vVALs = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Value2
        'build dictionary
        For v = LBound(vVALs, 1) To UBound(vVALs, 1)
            'overwrite method - faster (no error control)
            'writes name&position as key, ID as item
            dict.Item(Join(Array(vVALs(v, 2), vVALs(v, 3)), ChrW(8203))) = vVALs(v, 1)
        Next v

        'loop through the second table
        For v = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
            d = Join(Array(.Cells(v, 6).Value2, .Cells(v, 5).Value2), ChrW(8203))
            If dict.exists(d) Then _
                .Cells(v, 7) = dict.Item(d)
        Next v
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: dictionary_lookup_results]

Comment: I think OP only wants to replace the cell value from the dictionary if the supervisor name appears in the table at the same position that the ID appears in the dictionary. I could be completely wrong though...

Comment: No that sounds right. I chose to put the ID in a new column for demonstration purposes. If the OP wants to overwrite then he/she can change the 7 to a 6.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

Assuming your supervisor names are in column B starting in row 2:

```
Dim r As Long
Dim supervisorName As Range

For Each supervisorName In Range("B2:B" & Cells.(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Cells
    If superDictionary.Exists(supervisorName.Value) Then
        r = 2 '// First row with data in
        For Each key In superDictionary.Keys
            If superDictionary(key) = supervisorName.Value And supervisorName.Row = r Then
                supervisorName.Value = key
                Exit For
            Else
                r = r + 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```