# Excel VBA Dictionary: add matching criteria if the data doesn't match with dictionary

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I have been working on finding a way to add a matching criteria to another workbook almost this day, but I did not find anyway to do it yet. The example scenario is
the following, I have two workbooks (workbookA and workbookB) and each workbook has their own "Country" and "Value" lists. Kindly see sample tables per below.

```
Workbook("WorkA").Sheet1                  Workbook("workB").Sheet1
Country   Value                           Country     Value           
A          10                             B
B          15                             D
C          20                             E
D          25                             A
E          30
F          35
```

I finished matching value column by the following code:

```
Sub Test_match_fill_data()

Dim Dict As Object
Dim key As Variant
Dim aCell, bCell As Range
Dim i, j As Long
Dim w1, w2 As Worksheet


    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set w1 = Workbooks("workA").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set w2 = Workbooks("workB").Sheets("Sheet1")


    i = w1.Cells(w1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row


    For Each aCell In w1.Range("A6:A" & i)
        If Not Dict.exists(aCell.Value) Then 
            Dict.Add aCell.Value, aCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        End If
    Next

    j = w2.Cells(w2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    For Each bCell In w2.Range("A6:A" & j)
        For Each key In Dict
            If bCell.Value = key Then
                bCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Dict(key)
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

What I would like to do is to add some missing countries from "workA" (in this case are countries "C" and "F") and then redo matching process again to gathered all of data. Copy and paste solution is not suit to my case since I have to gather time series data (trade data) and it is possibly that some months my interested country will trade with new partners. I have tried to research on this in several websites and been deep down and adjusted my code with other people's codes as following link:
[Dictionary add if doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447736/dictionary-add-if-doesnt-exist), [Looping Through EXCEL VBA Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843975/looping-through-excel-vba-dictionary), [Optimise compare and match method using scripting.dictionary in VBA](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142294/optimise-compare-and-match-method-using-scripting-dictionary-in-vba), [A 'flexible' VBA approach to lookups using arrays, scripting dictionary](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142753/a-flexible-vba-approach-to-lookups-using-arrays-scripting-dictionary-and-user)

Can any potential gurus suggest me the solutions or ideas to deal with this kind of problems? It would be nice if you could explain your reasoning behind the code or any mistake I had made.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With minimal changes to your code:

```
Sub Test_match_fill_data()
    Dim Dict As Object
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set w1 = Workbooks("workA").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set w2 = Workbooks("workB").Sheets("Sheet1")

    i = w1.Cells(w1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    For Each aCell In w1.Range("A6:A" & i)
        Dict(aCell.Value) = aCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    Next

    j = w2.Cells(w2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    For Each bCell In w2.Range("A6:A" & j)
        If Dict.Exists(bCell.Value) Then
            bCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Dict(bCell.Value)
            Dict.Remove bCell.Value
        End If
    Next

    For Each key In Dict
        With w2.Cells(w2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
             .Value = key
            .Offset(,2) = Dict(key)
         End With
    Next
End Sub
```

while a slightly more condensed version of it could be the following:

```
Sub Test_match_fill_data()
    Dim Dict As Object
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim cell As Range

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With Workbooks("workA").Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each cell In .Range("A6", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
            Dict(cell.Value) = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        Next
    End With

    With Workbooks("workB").Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each cell In .Range("A6", .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
            If Dict.Exists(cell.Value) Then
                cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Dict(cell.Value)
                Dict.Remove cell.Value
            End If
        Next
        For Each key In Dict
            With .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                 .Value = key
                .Offset(, 2) = Dict(key)
             End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

for a "Fast&Furious" code you want massive use of array and dictionaries and limit excel sheet range accesses to the minimum

so the following code is obtained from my last one, but limiting excel sheets range accesses to initial data reading and final data writing, both in "one shot" mode (or nearly)

```
Sub Test_match_fill_data()
    Dim Dict As Object
    Dim iItem As Long
    Dim workACountries As Variant, workAValues As Variant
    Dim workBCountries As Variant, workBValues As Variant

    With Workbooks("workA").Sheets("Sheet1")
        workACountries = .Range("A6", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
        workAValues = .Range("C6:C" & .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For iItem = 1 To UBound(workACountries)
        Dict(workACountries(iItem, 1)) = workAValues(iItem, 1)
    Next

    With Workbooks("workB").Sheets("Sheet1")
        workBCountries = .Range("A6", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
        workBValues = .Range("C6:C" & .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With

    For iItem = 1 To UBound(workBCountries)
        If Dict.Exists(workBCountries(iItem, 1)) Then
            workBValues(iItem, 1) = Dict(workBCountries(iItem, 1))
            Dict.Remove workBCountries(iItem, 1)
        End If
    Next

    With Workbooks("workB").Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A6").Resize(UBound(workBCountries)).Value = workBCountries
        .Range("C6").Resize(UBound(workBCountries)).Value = workBValues

        .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(Dict.count).Value = Application.Transpose(Dict.Keys)
        .Cells(.Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(Dict.count).Value = Application.Transpose(Dict.Items)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @DisplayName, first of all thank you for your kind help and prompt response. After I tried using your code, I found a very tiny mistake on it. Without any editing, your code will return blank on common countries, but add missing countries and its value instead. It was my mistake that I could not have explained clearly about this. What I really want are both data from common countries and the missing ones. Still, I already joined your code with mine and it worked pretty well so far. Again, thank you for your suggestion, I am very appreciated :)

Comment: you are welcome. you may then consider marking the answer as accepted. thank you. while as for the "tiny mistake" you told about, please consider I adopted the `.Offset(,2)` from your code so it'd read "Values" from column C, i.e. two columns to the right of "Country" column (which is column A). With this assumption, I tested my code as per your data and it worked

Comment: Could I seek for your advice whether I should use this dictionary script or the dynamic solution as below post from @dwirony?. My condition is I want to process those file as fast as I can since they are ton of file waiting for process. I do not know which solution will I take me more time. Any opinions on this matter?

Comment: well, just try both! But it's commonly known that dicts and arrays approach is much much faster then worksheet cells read and write one

Comment: My very new knowledge about this. If that so, let me try both of these. Thanks again for your help and opinions. Cheers ;D

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use a dictionary for this - you can just go through every value in `Book1`, column `A`, check if it exists in the range in `Book2` column `A`, and if it does, you can port over its corresponding value - if it DOESN'T, add it to the end and bring over its associated value. This is a simple, dynamic solution.

Note the simple use of `.Find` to return the row position:

```
Sub Test_match_fill_data()

Dim aCell
Dim i, j As Long, keyrow As Long
Dim w1, w2 As Worksheet

Set w1 = Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1")
Set w2 = Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet1")

i = w1.Cells(w1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
j = w2.Cells(w2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each aCell In w1.Range("A2:A" & i)
    On Error Resume Next
    keyrow = w2.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=aCell, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
    On Error GoTo 0

    If keyrow = 0 Then
        w2.Range("A" & j + 1).Value = aCell
        w2.Range("B" & j + 1).Value = aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        j = j + 1
    Else
        w2.Range("B" & keyrow).Value = aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If

    keyrow = 0
Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: The order would be different if you just copy pasted it over - when this finds the first record that doesn't exist in `w2`, its added to the bottom and its values are brought over.

Comment: @DisplayName Oops, I pasted the wrong image! Thank you for noting that

Comment: Hi @dwirony, thank you for your helpful suggestion. As I am an inexperienced beginner on VBA coding, I could not generate that kind of dynamic solutions. Honestly, I much more like your code than mine since it was simple, easy to re-visit and well-organized to new coming data. Sorry for not giving you a correct mark as my headline concerning on VBA dictionary. Thank you for sharing your knowledge and taught me a simple dynamic solution. If I have a chance, I will adapt your code into my work for sure :)